# Insertar en una tabla el valor de una operación

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trasteando con SQL Server cómo hacer unos cálculos con unos valores que se van actualizando cada 10 minutos y quería ver cómo coger el valor resultante y meterlo en una tabla para que quede el dato almacenado, y además añadirle una columna con el nombre y otra con la fecha.

La consulta que hago es la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @start_interval datetime
SET @start_interval = DATEADD(day,-1, GETDATE())

SELECT

(select top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP)
from tabla
 WHERE TAG ='valor1'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_interval,tmdt)/(1440)))
*
100
/
((select top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP)
from tabla
 WHERE TAG ='valor1'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_interval,tmdt)/(1440)))
 +
 (select top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP) as VALUE
from biogas
 WHERE TAG ='valor2'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_interval,tmdt)/(1440))))
```

Lo que me devuelve el valor que busco, en este momento 4.5. Lo que busco es poder guardar este valor junto con el resto de columnas, una con el nombre la variable, y otra con el tiempo en el que se hace el registro quedando de la siguiente manera:

| metric | Value | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Variable | 4.5 | 2023-01-17 14:54:26.667 |

Pero no sé cómo hacer para insertar los datos y que queden como la tabla de arriba. Lo he intentado a lo bruto, pero nada:

```
insert into tabla 2 (metric, value, time)  values ('Variable',(select top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP)
from tabla
 WHERE TAG ='valor1'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_interval,tmdt)/(1440)))
*
100
/
((select top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP)
from tabla
 WHERE TAG ='valor1'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_interval,tmdt)/(1440)))
 +
 (select top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP) as VALUE
from tabla
 WHERE TAG ='valor2'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_interval,tmdt)/(1440)))), 
getdate())
```

Pero no la crea.

Comment: ¿Sabes que puedes insertar directamente desde un `SELECT`?  la sintaxis es `INSERT INTO TABLA (COL1, COL2) SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM OTRA_TABLA`

Comment: Buenas, he visto que el select no va precedido de un "values" como suele pasar con el "insert into". Ayer estuve trasteando y conseguí llegar a una solución que me vale, la he dejado como respuesta del post. También he editado el post para que sea más claro los objetivos que tenía. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he conseguido que me inserte los valores en la tabla con el siguiente código

```
insert into tabla 2 
select 
'Variable'as metric,
top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP)
from tabla
 WHERE TAG ='valor1'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_interval,tmdt)/(1440)))
*
100
/
((select top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP)
from tabla
 WHERE TAG ='valor1'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_interval,tmdt)/(1440)))
 +
 (select top (1) max (TEP) - min (TEP) as VALUE
from tabla
 WHERE TAG ='valor2'
 group by tag,
 floor(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@start_interval,tmdt)/(1440)))) as value, 
getdate()) as time
```

Comment: Esto no parece ser una respuesta a tu pregunta, sino parece una continuación de la misma. Si no es una respuesta, _bórrala_, y edita tu pregunta. La zona de respuestas es para respuestas _completas_ a la pregunta, y no olvides que el formato es _una pregunta, varias respuestas_, no _múltiples preguntas con respuestas mezcladas_.